# $routeProvider error when upgrading angular from 1.0.8 to 1.2.21

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing, ngroute

Previously , i used angular js 1.0.8
Now i updated the version from 1.0.8 to 1.2.21
But it is displaying error as below:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module auditApp due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeProvider
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.21/$injector/unpr?p0=%24routeProvider
    at http://localhost:8080/AuditTool...<omitted>...2)
```

And the $route provider functionality is not at all working .

Do anyone can help me in this regard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ngRoute` is not included any longer by default, which includes `$routeProvider`

You need to download and include the ngRoute package separately

1. Go to download [angular](https://angularjs.org/) and select additional downloads.
2. Then select *angular-route.js* or *angular-route.min.js*
3. Include the script in your project.
4. Make sure ngRoute is added as a dependency `angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute'])`

[Dependencies for $routeProvider listed here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider)

Comment: I included ngRoute. Now, there is no error . But the template is not rendering.